# PHP Sessions not working on IIS 7.5

Tags: php, session, iis

I have an IIS server with multiple virtual hosts running from the default site, these host all use PHP and create login sessions daily.

I recently added a new site (new domain) in IIS and the virtual directories I put in this site cant't create PHP sessions. I tried the following basic test which works in the default website.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 'my_test_value';
echo $_SESSION['test'];
```

So I load the page to store the session value then comment out the second line and load again and  I get..

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: test
```

Have I configured the site incorrectly or do I need to enable something in PHP, like I said the default site has not problems creating sessions, and this is the first time I have added a second site to IIS so I am a bit of a newbie.

Comment: Which version of PHP?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, PHP Version 5.3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by installing an instance of PHP 5.6 and pointing the new site to the new instance of PHP and leaving the old site pointing to 5.3

Answer (score 0):

In earlier versions of PHP 5.3, session_register be used.

```
session_start()
session_register('test');
$_SESSION['test'] = 'my_test_value';

echo $_SESSION['test'];
```

Session_Register() is deprecated.

But you should check that the variable exists with isset()

Example:
session_start();

```
if(isset($_SESSION['test']) && !empty($_SESSION['test'])){
    /* echo $_SESSION['test'] */
}
```

Comment: Sorry that does not fix my problem, I cant find any answers on-line. Can you have multiple iis sites using the same PHP.

Comment: You can have multiple sites using the same PHP, in fact that's kind of the default situation. If you want them to use different PHP versions/instances you actually have to create a mapping for each site to the instance of PHP you want to use.